# Presentation in pair - handing over

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

We will have small conference at our university and it is going to be held in English. I will speak there together with my colleague and it seems like I am going first and let him continue in the half of the presentation. What is the best phrase to say in the situation like this?

Let me hand over to my colleague?

Let my colleague continue?

Anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can "now turn it over to my colleague"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several phrases that might be suitable:

> Now I'll hand it over to my colleague
>
> My colleague will take it from here.
>
> Now I'll hand the microphone over to my colleague

Metaphors can be fun:

> I'll now yield the floor to my colleague
>
> I'll yield the rest of our time to my colleague

These expressions come from parliamentary procedure.  Might be fun if you're in a law school.

Comment: (Un)fortunately, it is some computer science stuff but thanks. Will use one of yours.